# How to select latest record out of a few potential found, in a Subquery

Tags: sql, teradata

I've got a table that stores consent record for a customer. Each time the status changes, a new record is created. I'm trying to establish on any given date whether there was a consent for that customer.

The thing I started with a a SUBQUERY was something like:

```
SELECT OPT_TYPE
FROM CONSENTS C
WHERE C.DATE < '20180101'
```

The problem is that there could be multiple records that match these conditions. Coming from PostgreSQL background, I found it strange that there is no LIMIT 1 option within Teradata. So, browsing the manual I found I could use QUALIFY icw RANK. So I tried expanding the query to:

```
SELECT OPT_TYPE
FROM CONSENTS C
WHERE C.DATE < '20180101'
QUALIFY RANK() OVER (ORDER BY C.DATE) = 1
```

Unfortunately this gives me a syntax error `Syntax error: Order-based Aggregate and Ordered Analytical Functions are not allowed in subqueries.`. Anyone who can tell me how to achieve this fairly straightforward thing? I know this is probably a Teradata noob question, so please spare me.

Sample Data

```
Date      Consent  Account_id
20180201  Opt_out  1
20171115  Opt_in   1
20170307  Opt_out  1
```

I'd like to find the record that was the latest at any given point in time. So if I'd query < 20180101, it should return Opt_in (record 2), if I'd query < 20171010, it should return Opt_out.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text, not images.

Comment: Added some sample data. This works perfectly when running a normal query though. Problem is that I am not able to use `QUALIFY RANK() OVER (ORDER BY C.DATE) = 1` in a subquery. But there is probably a more obvious way to select only a single record, based on a fixed sorting.

Comment: Instead of using rank in your qualify, use it to derive a column in your subquery/derived table.  Then you can filter by that column = 1. That might work, hard to say without seeing your full query.

Answer (score 1):

One method is:

```
select c.*
from consents c
where c.date = (select max(c2.date)
                from consents c2
                where c2.date < '20180101'
               );
```

In more recent versions you can do:

```
SELECT TOP (1) OPT_TYPE
FROM CONSENTS C
WHERE C.DATE < '20180101'
ORDER BY C.DATE DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

TOP & OLAP-functions are not allowed in a subquery because it might be a Correlated Subquery.

As workaround you can either rewrite it as a join or nest it in a Derived Table:

```
select ...
from mytable join
 (
   SELECT OPT_TYPE
   FROM CONSENTS C
   WHERE C.DATE < '20180101'
   QUALIFY RANK() OVER (ORDER BY C.DATE) = 1
 ) as dt
on ... 

select ...
from ...
where OPT_TYPE in
 ( 
   SELECT *
   FROM
    (
      SELECT OPT_TYPE
      FROM CONSENTS C
      WHERE C.DATE < '20180101'
      QUALIFY RANK() OVER (ORDER BY C.DATE) = 1
    ) as dt
 )
```

Btw, if your date column is actually a date you should use a *date literal* `DATE '2018-01-01'` instead of a string `'20180101'`.